# Can I replace ‘When’ by ‘As’ or ‘While’?

Tags: grammar, word-meaning

When reports came into London zoo that a puma had been sent, they were not taken seriously.

Can I replace ‘When’ by ‘As’ or ‘While’?

Answer (score 1):

When is the only one that really works without changing the rest of the sentence, as it seems to be in past tense:

> When reports came into London zoo that a puma had been sent, they were not taken seriously, but now that Mr Thatcher has been eaten, the police have changed their tune.
>
> While reports **are coming** into London zoo that a puma had been sent, they **are** not **being** taken seriously.
>
> As reports **come** into London zoo that a puma had been sent, they **are** not taken seriously.

It really depends on the context in which you are writing this, I'd be happy to help more if you provide the paragraph, but I'm a native English speaker so I cant quite put my finger on the while/as reasoning! :)

Comment: This first paragraph:  ‘Pumas are large, cat-like animals which are found in America. When reports came into London Zoo that a wild puma had been reported forty-five miles south of London, they were not taken seriously. However, as the evidence began to accumulate, experts from the Zoo felt obliged to investigate, for the description given by people who claimed to have seen the puma were extraordinarily similar.’     In the paragraph, it used ‘as’ in the past sense.

Comment: I think you are correct to use as in this context, but when would also work. I think it's to do with the tense you are using, but as I say, my knowledge is based on being native and what sounds correct, as opposed to awkward. One amend I would potentially make is: However, as the evidence began to accumulate, experts from the Zoo felt obliged to investigate, **since** the description given by people who claimed to have seen the puma were extraordinarily similar.

Comment: So with my question, can ‘as’ replace the ‘When’?

Comment: I've just realized you have two cases where this question is relevant. I think your second line needs to remain "when".

Comment: Why can not use ‘as’?

Comment: As I said, I can't comment on the clear rules surrounding this, but I believe that second sentence is completely talking about the past tense, where as the third sentence, it's present in the context of the rest of the sentence.

Comment: "As" can replace "when" in the OP sentence and it's still grammatically correct, but it slightly changes the meaning. When "as" introduces a temporal prepositional phrase, it emphasizes continuous or ongoing action rather than action that occurred at a specific moment in time. "When reports came in" suggests a specific time when reports arrived. "As reports came in" suggests some _duration_ of time during which reports arrived. Other than this difference the grammatical structure is the same and both are acceptable.

Comment: @Y.zeng The use of *as* at the start of a sentence like this is semantically questionable because it can be interpreted to mean *because*. While not wrong, I wouldn't recommend it in this context. Similarly, in this particular context, *while* can be ambiguously interpreted as *although*, so I wouldn't use it at the start of a sentence like this either. *When*, on the other hand, has no such ambiguous interpretation. (Note you can unambiguously use *as* and *while* if you rephrase the sentence so as not to *start* it with either of those words.)